# How to prevent a form input value from disappearing on click in other fields?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, formik, chakra-ui

The form `campaignid` input value is automatically filled in when the page is loaded. When I click on the other fields, it reset to default.

What can I do to prevent default and preserve my `campaignid` input value?

I'm using a [third party script](https://www.gkogan.co/blog/save-url-parameters/) to get URL parameters and insert them into `campaignid` value.

```
import { Button, FormControl, Input } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { Field, Form, Formik } from "formik";

import Script from "next/script";

export default function FormikExample() {
  return (
    <>
      <Script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gkogan/sup-save-url-parameters/sup.min.js" />

      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          name: "",
        }}
        onSubmit={(values) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            fetch(`https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/3660927/bte5w77/`, {
              method: "POST",
              body: JSON.stringify(values, null, 2),
            }),
              3000;
          });
        }}
      >
        {(props) => (
          <Form id="hero">
            <Field name="name">
              <FormControl>
                {({ field }) => <Input {...field} type="text" id="name" />}
              </FormControl>
            </Field>

            <Field name="email">
              <FormControl>
                {({ field }) => <Input {...field} type="email" id="email" />}
              </FormControl>
            </Field>

            <Field name="campaignid">
              {({ field }) => (
                <FormControl isReadOnly>
                  <Input {...field} type="hidden" value="" id="campaignid" />
                </FormControl>
              )}
            </Field>

            <Button id="submited" isLoading={props.isSubmitting} type="submit">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default of the submit form.
Use prevent default on your submit function, it will stop that behaviour. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

```
e.preventDefault()
```

Comment: Can you show me how?